# Can I get Python debugger pdb to output with Color?

Tags: python, debugging, terminal, pdb

I'm using PDB a lot and it seems it would be even better if I could add systax highlighting in color.

Ideally, I'd like to have to the path to the code a lighter color.
The line of actual code would be syntax highlighted.

I'm using OS X and the Terminal app. 
Python 2.7

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`pdb` doesn't support colorization.  However, it's not that hard to get it, even if you're a command-line addict (as I am;-) -- you don't have to switch to GUIs/IDEs just to get colorization while debugging Python.  In particular, command-line tools usually work *much* better when you're accessing a remote machine via SSH, saving a lot of the bandwidth and latency issues that any remote access to GUIs and IDEs can inflict on you;-).

Specifically, for the task you're asking about, consider [ipdb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb/0.1) (you also need [ipython](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipython/0.10), which offers a far more advanced shell than plain interactive Python, on which `ipdb` relies).  Both offer you good tab completion, enhanced tracebacks, *and* colorization -- `ipython` for your normal interactive work, `ipdb` with the same features when you're debugging (otherwise just about the same as `pdb`).

Comment: So do `$ python -m ipdb <mymodule>` and the output will be syntax highlighted. Using Python3 since this is ten years later.

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at [pdb++](https://github.com/antocuni/pdb) - it is a drop-in replacement for pdb that fills all your requirements and adds some other nice features such as tab completion and new commands such as watch and sticky.

Here is a sample config file that will enable colours (add this after creating the file: `touch ~/.pdbrc.py`):

```
import pdb

class Config(pdb.DefaultConfig):
    use_pygments = True
    pygments_formatter_class = "pygments.formatters.TerminalTrueColorFormatter"
    pygments_formatter_kwargs = {"style": "monokai"}
```

Answer (score 9):

You could try [pudb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb/), which works in the terminal and looks like this:

[image: pudb screenshot]

I haven't tried some of the options mentioned in other answers, but to judge from the PyPI pages, pudb is better maintained and better documented.

Comment: The current versions have a few color schemes that are quite nice (not gaudy like the default shown above)

Answer (score 0):

This might not possible for you, but have you tried using a graphical debugger (like the one in eclipse/[pydev](http://pydev.org/))? It will give you your syntax highlighting and much more.

I only use pdb directly if I don't have an option, because a graphical interface is just that much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone hit the problem with colorization in a console.

My console had white background while ipdb was also adding rather light colors to syntax (for example variables were white). Pressing man ipython shows that we have 3 colors available: 'nocolor', 'linux', 'LightBG'. Ipdb was in my case installed via easy_install into my virtualenv. So it was trivial to look into ipdb source and modify it (hint search for ipdb/**init**.py in your env). Then I've modified following:

```
def set_trace():
    ip = ipapi.get()
    + def_colors = ip.options.colors
    + def_colors = 'LightBG'
    Pdb(def_colors).set_trace(sys._getframe().f_back)
```

It's a kinda hackish solution but well its for debugging purpose on my working station so its sufficient. But if anyone finds something better. Please send me a message on what to do.

Comment: Does this work? i have `IndentationError: unexpected indent` on the lines with a `+` sign

Comment: That code was pseudo-code. pluses were only indications of where I put new lines of code (similar to how patches are formatted). Drop plusses and should work, on the other hand, it's 2020 so I stopped using it altogether, nowadays it works out of the box. :-)